# Query SQL for extracting dates in a single column

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I need to extract the last 2 years month end dates and the last 10 days.
Example:
If I take 2024-01-30 as the reference date
all the last 24 end of the month must end up in it:
2023-12-31
2023-11-30
2023-10-30
etc..

- the last 10 days:

2024-01-29
2024-01-28
2024-01-27
2024-01-26
2024-01-25
etc

this in a single column.

The column (type date) that contains the month ends is called d_fine_mese and the other is called d_periodo.

I expect help in finding the solution to my problem

Comment: Please show us your solution attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer:

```
SELECT
    (date_trunc('month', generate_series('01/30/24'::timestamp - interval '24 months', '01/30/24'::timestamp, '1 month')) + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval)::date AS m
UNION
SELECT
    (generate_series('01/30/24'::timestamp - '10 day'::interval, '01/30/24'::timestamp, '1 day'))::date AS m
ORDER BY
    m;

  m      
------------
 2022-01-31
 2022-02-28
 2022-03-31
 2022-04-30
 2022-05-31
 2022-06-30
 2022-07-31
 2022-08-31
 2022-09-30
 2022-10-31
 2022-11-30
 2022-12-31
 2023-01-31
 2023-02-28
 2023-03-31
 2023-04-30
 2023-05-31
 2023-06-30
 2023-07-31
 2023-08-31
 2023-09-30
 2023-10-31
 2023-11-30
 2023-12-31
 2024-01-20
 2024-01-21
 2024-01-22
 2024-01-23
 2024-01-24
 2024-01-25
 2024-01-26
 2024-01-27
 2024-01-28
 2024-01-29
 2024-01-30
 2024-01-31
```